# Using JQuery Tabs inside a (MVC) Partial View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, tabs, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a partial view that renders a bunch of controls, and I also want it to contain a series of JQuery Tabs. The tabs render fine:

```
    <div id="comment-tabs">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#comment-tabs-1">Comments</a></li>
        <li><a href="#comment-tabs-2">Contact Events</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="comment-tabs-1">
        <p>Comments</p>
      </div>
      <div id="comment-tabs-2">
        <p>Contact Events</p>
      </div>
    </div>

<script> $( function() {$( "#comment-tabs" ).tabs();});</script>
```

However, when I click on any of the tabs my whole page just re-loads the page URL. It seems it is treating the  tags as normal hyperlinks and not using them in their 'Tab' capacity.

Has anyone else had this experience using Partial views like this... Am I doing something wrong or missing something?

Comment: I have an example where I have a page that contains 2 tabs of which each tabs content comes from a partial view. I can post you my set up if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and example. I think you may have miss-read my issue though. I am not rendering a Partial View inside the tab - I am rendering the tab inside the partial view. Appreciate the reply though! I am going through the rest of the code on the partial view and am finding some missing closing Divs (the page is created dynamically) so am starting think this may have something to do with it. Am testing now.

Comment: Oh ok...wel lhope you get it sorted. Cheers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found that this is a JQuery thing that has come up before in my place of work. The simple solution is to add class="non-link" to the anchor...

```
<li><a href="#comment-tabs-1" class="non-link">Comments</a></li>
<li><a href="#comment-tabs-2" class="non-link">Contact Events</a></li>
```

Works a treat!

Answer (score 1):

Below is my current working set up for a page that contains 2 tabs, each sourced from a partial view. The main page has a view model that has a separate class for each tabs content. In this example, the view model would have 2 classes called Tab1Model and Tab2Model.

```
<div>
    <div>
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active">
            @Html.Partial("_Tab1PartialView", Model.Tab1Model)
        </div>

        <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
            @Html.Partial("_Tab2PartialView", Model.Tab2Model)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've noticed that you seem to be missing few attributes from the list elements as well. I presume you are using bootstrap css.

I've modified your mark up to match mine.

```
<div id="comment-tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#comment-tabs-1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Comments</a></li>
        <li><a href="#comment-tabs-2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Contact Events</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="comment-tabs-1">
        //Comments PartialView ref here
    </div>
    <div id="comment-tabs-2">
        //Contact Events PartialView ref here
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope that helps.